# How can I include missing items using groupby in Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

Let's say I have a dataframe with the following columns: date, time, day, month, year, description, price, type, manufacturer

Using pandas and `value_counts()`, I can get the count for every unique item in a column:

```
df.manufacturer.value_counts()
```

Also, using groupby I can get the average price for every day in my data:

```
df.groupby("day").price.mean()
```

The issue with that is there are 7 days in total but in my data there might be only 5 or 6, so I need to add the missing days with the mean being zero or None.

In general, if I have a specific list how do I include the missing items when I do something like value_counts or groupby operations ?

Comment: Can you add sample data?

Answer (score 4):

I think you can convert days to `categorical`s, so then if use [`groupby + mean`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/categorical.html#operations) get `NaN`s for missing categories:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'day': ['Monday','Tuesday','Tuesday','Tuesday','Thursday'],
    'price': list(range(5))
})
print (df)
        day  price
0    Monday      0
1   Tuesday      1
2   Tuesday      2
3   Tuesday      3
4  Thursday      4

cats = ['Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday', 'Saturday', 'Sunday']
df['day'] = pd.Categorical(df['day'], categories=cats, ordered=True)
print(df.groupby("day", as_index=False).price.mean())
         day  price
0     Monday    0.0
1    Tuesday    2.0
2  Wednesday    NaN
3   Thursday    4.0
4     Friday    NaN
5   Saturday    NaN
6     Sunday    NaN
```

Another solution is [`reindex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.reindex.html) by all posible categories:

```
cats = ['Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday', 'Saturday', 'Sunday']

print(df.groupby("day").price.mean().reindex(cats))
day
Monday       0.0
Tuesday      2.0
Wednesday    NaN
Thursday     4.0
Friday       NaN
Saturday     NaN
Sunday       NaN
Name: price, dtype: float64

print(df.groupby("day").price.mean().reindex(cats, fill_value=0))
day
Monday       0
Tuesday      2
Wednesday    0
Thursday     4
Friday       0
Saturday     0
Sunday       0
Name: price, dtype: int64
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use [Categorical Data](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/categorical.html) for this. Below is a minimal example.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame([['Monday', 5], ['Monday', 6], ['Monday', 3],
                   ['Tuesday', 1], ['Tuesday', 8]],
                  columns=['day', 'value'])

# list days in order
day_list = ['Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday', 'Saturday', 'Sunday']

# convert to categorical
df['day'] = df['day'].astype('category')

# set categories and ordered=True
df['day'] = df['day'].cat.set_categories(day_list, ordered=True)

# perform groupby and fillna with 0
res = df.groupby('day').mean().fillna(0)
```

Result:

```
              value
day                
Monday     4.666667
Tuesday    4.500000
Wednesday  0.000000
Thursday   0.000000
Friday     0.000000
Saturday   0.000000
Sunday     0.000000
```